# Webscraping with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I tried to use rvest to get all 471 cases on this site, but each time could only get 25 cases (regardless whether the list is expanded or not).  Any help would be appreciated.

```
library("rvest")
url <- "http://investmentpolicyhub.unctad.org/ISDS?status=100"
cases <- url %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="cases-list"]') %>%
html_table()
View(cases)
```

Thank you.

Comment: It uses an XHR request to load additional cases and the web server checks for javascript when trying to load the XHR request URL so you'll need to use RSelenium.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you have to click the "Show all" button to show the rest of the table, which you can't do with rvest. Thus, using RSelenium to navigate and rvest to parse,

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

pJS <- phantom()    # install PhantomJS if necessary
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', 'a#loadWholeList')
button$clickElement()

Sys.sleep(60)    # or just wait a while, or rerun the following bits till they work

html <- remDr$getPageSource()

cases <- html[[1]] %>% read_html() %>%
    html_node('table#cases-list') %>%
    html_table()

if(nrow(cases) > 26){
    remDr$close()
    pJS$stop()
}
```

Because you're directing a [headless] browser, the bits after the clicking may give you 25 rows or 471 rows, depending on if the table has finished loading. The table is pretty big, so it takes a while to load, just like in a normal browser. If you don't get everything, wait a while and run the lines after `Sys.sleep` again.

With patience, though:

```
tail(cases[, 1:3])
##     No. Year of initiation            Short casename
## 466 466               1995      Goetz v. Burundi (I)
## 467 467               1995   Leaf Tobacco v. Albania
## 468 468               1994   Gruslin v. Malaysia (I)
## 469 469               1994 Saar Papier v. Poland (I)
## 470 470               1993              AMT v. Zaire
## 471 471               1987         AAPL v. Sri Lanka
```

Comment: Alistaire, thank you so much for help. It works great, but took me a while to get phantomjs to work, and then I noticed that I had to replace 26 inside "if(nrow(cases) > 26)" with 471 to get all cases :))..

Comment: `remDr$close()` and `pJS$stop()` just shut down the remote driver and PhantomJS. They're wrapped in a conditional so they won't run unless you've got the right data. If you're going to change the condition to 471, you should also change it to `>=`, or you'll never shut them down.